# How can i click Google search result with selenium-webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have problem with following task:

1. Open Google start page
2. Type request in search form
3. Choose result where url matches some given url(for example http://www.theguardian.com)

Currently i have this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com/")

search_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/input[1]")
search_form.send_keys("guardian")
search_form.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,"http://www.theguardian.com")]').click()
```

It succesfully executes first 2 subtasks but when on last line throws exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[starts-with(@href,\"http://www.theguardian.com\")]"}
```

Also i have this script which satisfies only last subtask:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
q = "guardian"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + q + "&start=" + str(counter))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,"http://www.theguardian.com")]').click()
```

I works OK. My question is why first script throws exception on how can i modify it so it opens search result as second script does?

**UPDATE:**

As Bart and Shubham mentioned in comments, problem was in that i was trying to find element on page that wasn't yet loaded. So solution is to use 'wait'.

Selenium-webdriver provides 2 types of 'wait' -- *explicit* and *implicit* more on that in [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html).

For my solution i used implicit wait. Basically, it's telling WebDriver to wait for certain amount of time to find an element if it's not immediately available.

For that i just added 1 line to script:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below ...

Try to put some wait from first place

The code is in java but it is very similar/near to python, take  a reference from it

You can check everytime that your element is present or not in your HTML DOM to prevent from error/failer of script. like below:-

```
  if (driver.findElements(By.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,"http://www.theguardian.com')).size() != 0) {  
            YOUR FIRST Working code  
            System.out.println("element exists");     
        }  
  else{
           Your second working code    
      }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is because the elements the first version is not yet on the page. If you create a "wait until element is present" kind of loop (do not know if it exists by heart) then it should work.

The second example does work because browser.get only returns if the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, Bart! Found solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this video, you can see how it can be done:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUBwtLG9hbs

Move to 12:30 to see it in action: Go to google.com, type something in the search box and click on a search result.